# in svg: translate vs position x and y

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

When I want to position simple objects such as `rect` or `line` should I use `transform` attribute or `x` and `y` attributes?

```js
// this
d3.selectAll('rect')
    .attr('x', d => d)
    .attr('y', 0)

// or this?
d3.selectAll('rect')
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d}, 0)`);
```

What is the performance difference?

Comment: it is said that transform forces the browser to use the gpu to render stuff. I observed a noticable difference in android browsers by using transform3d. But with others, the performance was the same.

Comment: @ParthikGosar you can't `transform3d` elements in SVG.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In SVG `transform` is not hardware accelerated. They have around the same performance for single elements (in my experience). However, I use `transform` more to move thing around because in SVG not all elements have a `x` or `y` attributes, consider...

```
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" />
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
<path d="M 0 0 L 100 100" />
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
```

You must write a different implementation for each of these elements if you are not using `transform`. One area where `transform` is indeed faster is moving a large number of elements, if you have...

```
<g transform="translate(100, 100)">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
  <path d="M 0 0 L 100 100" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
</g>
```

It will be less processing intensive than moving each element individually

Comment: I second the recommendation for using `transform` for moving things around. Another minor thing is that it modifies one attribute instead to two, which is better in general. I know of at least one implementation that do optimize certain things related to transforms in svg.

Comment: Any idea if using css transform will fetch gain or is it the same?I have an app where I zoom into the mouse point for every mouse wheel and it is re-flowing , re-painting the whole view-port. I am looking if I can achieve some advantage by hardware acceleration,

Comment: Setting the SVG's style to `position: absolute` seem to cause neither `transform="translate(..., ...)"` to work, nor setting style's `top` and `left` to work... leaving `x` and `y` attributes on the SVG as the only option. Unless something else is causing that behaviour in my case.